# Nuxt. Property or method "posts" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt js for this project. Here i am using the function 
asyncData to fetch data on the server side. That's, why i cant, set data to the "data" because all data is fetched on the server. But i have an error in the console "Property or method "posts" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render...".

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-list v-for="item in posts">
            <v-list-tile :key="item.id">
                <v-list-tile-content>
                    <h1>{{item.title}}</h1>
                </v-list-tile-content>
            </v-list-tile>
        </v-list>
    </div>
</template>

export default {
        asyncData() {
return axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
                .then(response => {
                    return {posts: response.data}
                })
        }
    }
```

Due to the docs, https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data i have only to use "posts"

Comment: If the above code is an exact copy of your actual code it isn't working because you need your `export default { ...` wrapped in '<script>` tags. Also you can disregard the answer below from @이준형 because it is wrong. What you have is otherwise fine.

Comment: same issue using vue storefront (that based on nuxt)

Answer (score 4):

The `asyncData()` method is only working in [pages](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/pages/).

From the officall nuxt.js docs:

**Updated:** [Async data in components](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching/#async-data-in-components)

1. Use the new fetch hook that is available in Nuxt 2.12 and later versions.
2. Make the API call in the mounted hook and set data properties when loaded. Downside: Won't work for server side rendering.
3. Make the API call in the asyncData method of the page component and pass the data as props to the sub components. Server rendering will work fine. Downside: the asyncData of the page might be less readable because it's loading the data for other components.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned the `asyncData` hook is not available in components but only for pages.

In Nuxt JS 2.12 though a new `fetch` hook was introduced, which navigates around the issue: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching#async-data-in-components

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        posts: []
      }
    },
    async fetch() {
      this.posts = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(response =>
        response.data
      )
    }
  }
</script>
```